# Put Javascript Array Values into Mongodb Collection Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have a Javascript Array filled with mean Values and I want to insert them into a collection with a field named "mean". The Field "mean" already exists and has already values in them and now I want to update them with the values of the Array. To be more specific: I want the first Value of the Array to be in the first Document under the field "mean" and so on. I have 98 Documents and the Array has also a length of 98.

The Collection looks like this with the name "cmean":

```
{ 
    "_id" : "000", 
    "mean" : 33.825645389680915

}
{ 
    "_id" : "001", 
    "mean" : 5.046005719077798 

}
```

and the Array:

```
[
    33.89923155012405, 
    5.063347068609219
]
```

Comment: lastedit?? what syntax is this ? use find in update?

Comment: @chridam answer is right , just missing } in line4

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: @chridam Works perfectly. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method on the array to iterate it and update the collection. Use the index to get the `_id` to be used in the update query, something like the following:

```
meansArray.forEach(function(mean, idx) {
    var id = db.cmean.find({}).skip(idx).limit(1).toArray()[0]["_id"];
    db.cmean.updateOne(
        { "_id": id },
        { "$set": { "mean": mean } },
        { "upsert": true }
    );
});
```

---

For large collections, you can streamline your db performance using **[`bulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)** as follows:

```
var ops = [];

meansArray.forEach(function(mean, idx) {
    var id = db.cmean.find({}).skip(idx).limit(1).toArray()[0]["_id"];
    ops.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": id },
            "update": { "$set": { "mean": mean } },
            "upsert": true            
        }
    });

    if (ops.length === 1000 ) {
        db.cmean.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }
})

if (ops.length > 0)
    db.cmean.bulkWrite(ops);
```

Comment: Are all the _id's zero padded?

Comment: No after the zeroes there are names

Answer (score 0):

```
update({"_id": id}, $set: {"mean": myArray}, function(res, err) { ... });
```

If you are using mongoose, you also have to change data model from string to array.